# Javascript [this] keyword binding with new

Tags: javascript, this

when reading the book [You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#chapter-2-this-all-makes-sense-now)

I found this example about `this` binding:

```
function foo(something) {
  this.a = something;
}

var obj1 = {
 foo: foo
};

var obj2 = {};

obj1.foo( 2 );
console.log( obj1.a ); // 2

obj1.foo.call( obj2, 3 );
console.log( obj2.a ); // 3

var bar = new obj1.foo( 4 );
console.log( obj1.a ); // 2
console.log( bar.a ); // 4
```

I don't understand why after the execution of new obj1.foo(4) `console.log(obj1.a)` prints `2` and not `4`. And if I comment the line `obj1.foo(2)` the result of the log above is `undefined`.

Comment: Because when you use `new`, the `this` value will be a new object. See [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1529630)

Comment: When I tried to modify my question with the answer of Mike C in my mind, I understood very well my problem.Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because any function can be a constructor. Imagine if you used `foo` by itself:

```
var obj3 = new foo(3);
```

You'd expect to get an object similar too `{ a: 3 }`, right?

This still works even if the function is attached to something else. Every time you use `new` you're creating a new object, not changing an existing one.

In the first instance, you're using the function as a method:

```
obj1.foo(2);
```

In this case, the context is set to `obj1` since it's the one that invoked it. But when you use `new` a brand new object is created and that new object is used as the context.

Comment: I understand very well now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

When you call this `obj1.foo( 2 )` you execute the method of `obj1` passing as an argument  the 2. When `foo` is executed defines a property called `a` to the *calling* object and assigns to it the value of `something`, 2 in this case. The `calling` object in this case is `obj1`. So for this reason `obj1` acquires a property called `a` with the value of 2.

> And if I comment the line : obj1.foo(2) the result of the log above is
>   undefined.

This is happens because if you comment the line you mentioned. The `obj1` doesn't acquire a property `a`. Hence `a` is undefined in this case. Generally, speaking, if we consider an empty object `obj`, `obj = {}`. If you do the following:

```
obj.a
```

You define a property called `a` on the object `obj`. Furthermore, if you do the following:

```
obj.a = 4;
```

You do two things, you define the property `a` and you assign a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's break it down to smaller steps.

First off, `obj1.foo` calls the `foo` function.
The `foo` function takes one argument and assigns that argument to the `a` key of the object that is calling foo (it's a bit more complicated than that, I can elaborate afterwards if you'd like).

So when you call `obj1.foo(2)`, you're calling the `foo` method, passing in the parameter `2` by the perspective of the `obj1` object. That is why `obj1.a` will equal 2.
Since that's the command that assigns a value to `obj1.a`, the omission of that call will cause `obj1.a` to be undefined.